# Suite like adobe for ubuntu 14.0.4

Tags: 14.04, adobe

I need some softwares of the adobe suite , like Photoshop, Illustrator and others. I know that theres Ubuntu studio, but at the same time i need to write code, mostly ruby.
So, my question is, what options do i have if i need a creative suite and also code?
Maybe some softwares and not all the OS Ubuntu Studio.
Can you please Help me?
Thanks

Comment: The GIMP ( http://www.gimp.org/ ) is probably the closest alternative to Photoshop. You can also try running Photoshop itself through wine.

Comment: gr8! thanks, and what about fl studio or illustrator, what options do i have?

Comment: You can try Inkscape for an Illustrator alternative, and I have no idea about fl studio.

Answer (score 0):

**[LMMS](http://lmms.io/) : Linux MultiMedia Studio (alternatives of FL Studio) :**

LMMS is a free cross-platform alternative to commercial programs like Small FL Studio iconFL Studio, which allow you to produce music with your computer. This includes the creation of melodies and beats, the synthesis and mixing of sounds, and arranging of samples. You can have fun with your MIDI-keyboard and much more; all in a user-friendly and modern interface.

**[GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) (alternatives of Photoshop) :**

GIMP is a freely distributed program for such tasks as photo retouching, image composition and image authoring. It can be used as a simple paint program, an expert quality photo retouching program, an online batch processing system, a mass production image renderer, an image format converter, and more.

**[Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/) (alternatives of Illustrator) :**

An Open Source vector graphics editor, with capabilities similar to Illustrator, CorelDraw, or Xara X, using the W3C standard Scalable Vector Graphics (SVG) file format.

Inkscape supports many advanced SVG features (markers, clones, alpha blending, etc.) and great care is taken in designing a streamlined interface. It is very easy to edit nodes, perform complex path operations, trace bitmaps and much more. We also aim to maintain a thriving user and developer community by using open, community-oriented development.

(I get these informations from [alternativeto.net](http://alternativeto.net/))